# Regex to transpose somewhat tricky last name, first name , title

Tags: regex

Is it possible to use one regex to convert both

```
Doe, John C., Jr., M.D.
Doe, Jane, M.D.
```

to read

```
John C. Doe Jr., M.D.
Jane Doe, M.D.
```

Comment: So in other words, remove all commas BUT the last one ?

Comment: @Enissay It's also reordering things -- the first name s moved from second position to first.

Comment: What's your exact input?

Comment: Does everyone have a title at the end? If someone can be `Jr.` without a title, it will be difficult.

Comment: @Barmar yes, some quite lengthy. Doctors have large egos

Comment: According to your examples, we're always placing [Last Name], [First Name], [Titles] and changing to [First Name] [Last Name], [Titles]. Is that fair to say? If so, doesn't this just become splitting up the string on the first 2 commas it encounters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
^([^,]+),\s([^,]+),(?:(\s[^,]+),)?\s([^,]+)$
```

with

```
$2 $1$3, $4
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/gV5sM0/2)

Comment: Is there realistically any difference between what you posted and `^([^,]+),\s([^,]+),(.*)$` ?

Comment: Possibly not, that seems to work too: https://regex101.com/r/gV5sM0/3. Post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Barmar's answer works for the specified examples, but there's a possibly simpler solution which should satisfy our input:

Replace `^([^,]+),\s([^,]+),(.*)$`  with `$2 $1$3`

We replace the `(?:(\s[^,]+),)?\s([^,]+)` with a simpler `(.*)` that grabs all titles after the first name (we don't care about the specifics of what's in these titles).